# Equal exchange on Ahmokea

Tags: xenobiology

Me and my friend have a passion project where we mainly focus on a habitable planet; Ahmokea.

For a little while we wanted to include ammonia in the atmosphere on a large scale so it could be part of the animals & plant's equal exchange (just like how O2 is made into CO2 by us and the CO2 into O2 by plants.) But the thing is, recently I've tried looking deeper into it to see how realistic that would be and ammonia wouldn't really work because ammonia would kill most of it's life (from what I've heard), so I don't really know what could be an alternative to this idea.

Is there any atoms or molecules that could be part of the equal exchange on Ahmokea?

(Sorry for my terrible English/spelling.)

Also, forgot to add: Ahmokea's atmosphere mostly is composed of nitrogen and oxygen just like on Earth. The ammonia would have been a low percentage but significant enough to affect the life forms on the planet. The plants also use a pigment called "retinal" instead of chlorophyll, I don't exactly know if that is significant or not.

My friend and I thought of adding nitrifying bacteria in the process of the animals and plants breathing, but we aren't sure if that's realistic enough that it would work in general.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add, but me and my friend thought of adding nitrifying bacteria in the process of the animals and plants breathing, but we aren't so sure if that's realistic enough of if that would work in general.

Comment: The range of atmospheres that are tolerable to animals who evolved specifically for it, and are toxic to humans is incredibly broad. Can you [edit] this to ask a more specific question?

Comment: alright then, i do find my question to be too simple aswell

Comment: "The plants also use a pigment called "retinal" instead of chloroplast": chloroplasts are the organelles that contain the photosynthesizing pigments, you presumably mean chlorophyll. But it doesn't really make a difference unless you have some specific photosynthetic reaction in mind that depends on the atmospheric composition being hostile to humans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Nitrogen causes significant impairment at pressures above about 4 atm, and will cause unconsciousness and death at sufficiently high pressure.
- Oxygen causes damage to the central nervous system, lungs, and eyes at more than about a third of an atmosphere. The effects are a function of time and pressure and individual tolerance, but include seizures, tunnel vision, dizziness, confusion, etc. Note that increasing oxygen levels will also increase fire hazards, though.
- Our bodies use CO2 buildup to regulate respiration, and too much atmospheric CO2 will disrupt that as well as disturbing blood pH, which many things are sensitive to.
- Levels of ammonia that are dangerous to us certainly don't rule out life. You would need a biological source that constantly replenishes it though, and it is energy-intensive to make, which is why few organisms do so.

Then there are things like carbon monoxide that is mainly a hazard because we use hemoglobin for oxygen transport, or hydrogen cyanide which interferes with a very specific biochemical pathway in mitochondria, and might just not be an issue for alien life.

Comment: The amount of nitrogen and oxygen is roughly the same on Earth. Also my friend basically said the same for the ammonia, which is why we originally wanted to have nitrifying bacteria in the process. So I think we might actually keep the ammonia, I just have to ask a more specific question on how it'll work later. Thank you for your anwser.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I can think of is a very high concentration of carbon dioxide, mainly at or above the 5,500 PPM value as stated here
[1993-1994 ACGIH TLV: 5,000 ppm (9,000 mg/m3) TWA](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/idlh/124389.html)

The idea is there is enough oxygen for life as we know it. However, humans have not evolved to handle this amount of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere. One good way to support the statement that this planet has a higher concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> is being further outside the habitable zone we are accustomed to, so if plant life consumes too much of the CO<sub>2</sub> the greenhouse effect will be reduced and the planet will be too cold. This planet would be more susceptible to the "[snowball earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth)" effect and therefore would be more dependent on volcanic activity to replenish carbon dioxide.

Ammonia would not be sustainable in an earth-like atmosphere because it would oxidize into water and release the nitrogen. So if you are looking for a more exotic atmosphere, you may try chlorine, like in [chlorine planets](https://planetstar.fandom.com/wiki/Chlorine_planet). Now you may say that chlorine would be worse than ammonia. It is true for life on Earth. It may be possible, however, that life on that planet has evolved to live in a chlorine-rich atmosphere. When oxygen-based photosynthesis appeared on the planet, many life forms have suffered from the "[great oxidation event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxidation_Event)". However, many organisms have adapted and evolved to what we see today.

Comment: Why would ammonia dissolving into the water be a dealbreaker?  I'm not following the logic here.  Lots of stuff dissolves into the oceans and there is even already a crapload of ammonia (technically ammonium as its aqueous) in ours from peeing fish.  Is it the assumption that the atmosphere would run out of ammonia because its dissolving into the oceans?  Because the same thing happens with CO2 and oxygen and its still there because it gets replaced.  Besides, chlorine is just as volatile as ammonia.  Like ammonia and oxygen, it wouldn't be able to remain there absent replacement.

Comment: @Jeremiah As I understood the question, Ammonia is also present in the atmosphere. It would be hard to breathe for humans. Ammonia in the water would not affect them as long as they don't swim in it or drink it. Oceans would normally absorb it and that remaining in the atmosphere would be bad for the humans.

Comment: Ah ok.  Well that is true.  The question isn't regarding humans though, but aliens on Ahmokea.  I guess what confused me is this:  "Ammonia would not be sustainable in an earth-like atmosphere because it would oxidize into water and release the nitrogen. So if you are looking for a more exotic atmosphere, you may try chlorine".  Chlorine is no more viable for humans than ammonia, and I don't see how either is more viable than the other as an atmospheric component on an alien world.

Answer (score 4):

I once toyed around with a speculative biology project where I designed the biochemistry and physiology of a creature I called the "siphon sloth".  Most of the details of the animal's physiology aren't relevant here, but the primary impetus for the exercise was to consider how thermoregulation might work on a very hot planet.  Organisms on this theoretical nameless planet didn't struggle to keep warm, as we do on earth, but to keep cool.  There aren't "warm and cold blooded" animals, but "cool and hot blooded" animals, and the siphon sloth was initially just a thought experiment about how a "cool blooded" animal in such an ecosystem could work.

The reason I bring this up is that my cooling mechanism involved hijacking the nitrogenous waste removal system that, in us, produces urine.  The ammonia would be extracted from the blood and concentrated but, rather than simply being expelled, would then be pumped into a blood vessel rich, sac-like organ where it could expand, absorbing heat like an old ammonia air conditioner.  This expanded ammonia would then be expelled from the body as gaseous waste.

On this planet, there would be a good reason for there to be a high concentration of ammonia in the atmosphere, as it is constantly being replenished by the prevalence of "cool blooded" organisms on the planet.  Your planet needs some sort of mechanism like this, some reason why the things on this planet are making loads of ammonia.  The issue of ammonia being toxic isn't an issue really.  If you evolved in it it's not going to be toxic to you.  The big issue is how did that ammonia get up there, and the answer is going to be "someone needed to make it to do something that keeps them from dying".  Once that happens and atmospheric ammonia is a reality, everything else is going to figure out ways to either tolerate or use it.